# data.table join based on switched string combinations

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have `df1` which I would like to merge with `df2` based on a common field `id`

`id` is always in the form of `21_2342_A_C` (i.e. `num_num_char_char`). I want to merge `df2` into `df1` if either of the last two fields `(sep="_")` in `id` are switched.

So, if `ID` in `df1` is `21_2342_A_C`, then I want it to match if the entry in `df2` is either `21_2342_A_C` or `21_2342_C_A`.

Is this possible using data.table? I've developed a cumbersome way involving creating two different columns and doing two different joins, but I was hoping there'd be a more elegant solution. I'll also happily take a non data.table solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also includes creating two additional columns but only 1 merge:

```
dt <- data.table(
  id = c("21_2342_A_C", "21_2342_C_A", "21_2342_A_B")
)
```

1. extract number and character part of id
2. sort character part
3. merge if number and character parts are same
4. remove merges on itself and/or duplicated merges (if row i is merged to row j then row j is merged on row i)

```
dt[, row_id := seq_len(.N)]
dt[, (c("id1", "id2")) := transpose(str_extract_all(dt$id, "([0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4})|([A-Z]_[A-Z])"))]
dt[, id2 := map_chr(str_split(id2, "_"), ~str_c(sort(.x), collapse = ""))]
res <- dt[dt, on = .(id1, id2)][row_id < i.row_id]

res[, c("row_id", "id1", "id2", "i.row_id") := NULL]
```

Answer (score 2):

I also could not figure out how to do it without an intermediate id.
Here is my take:

```
df1 <- data.table(V1= "hello", id= "21_2342_A_C")
df2 <- data.table(V1= c("world1", "world2"), id= c("21_2342_A_C", "21_2342_C_A"))

sort_id <- function(x)
{
  x <- unlist(tstrsplit(x, "_"))
  return(paste0(c(x[1:2], sort(x[3:4])), collapse= "_"))
}

df1[, id2:= sort_id(id), id]
df2[, id2:= sort_id(id), id]

merge(df1, 
      df2, 
      "id2")
```